# Comment box and photo albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I retrieve photos albums from a fan page with the Graph API and I would know if it is possible to display on the "comments box" the same comments from a photo on my website as comments written by users on facebook (to avoid dispersion from a same photo)

If I set the "link" url from the graph API on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/, no comment is retrieved.

Thx !

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the comments on the image by calling the /comments endpoint on the GraphAPI URL. You can get more details in the [documentation directly](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).

Such as this: `https://graph.facebook.com/20531316728/comments`

You will then get back a collection of comments that you can display on your site. The return would look similar to this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "{ID}_{ID}",
            "from": {
                "name": "GAbii SUn",
                "id": "{ID}"
            },
            "message": "bno eso creo y no se si estan en ese restaurante",
            "created_time": "2011-04-28T13:42:45+0000"
        },
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/comments?format=json&limit=25&offset=25"
    }
}
```

Note: I stripped out the IDs, as expected to protect the privacy of the user.